# Count numbers in a range, but remove any number containing a specific number from the count

Tags: python, count, range

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0,1001):
    if '5' not in str(i):
        sum = sum + i
        i += 1
    print(sum)
```

This is what I have so far and I hope you can see my intention is to print the total sum of numbers ranging from 1 to 1000 while removing any number that contains the number 5 along the way.

I am new to coding and I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Try to avoid use `sum` built-in function as your variable name.

Comment: You could try this `generator expression` is faster: ` total = sum(x for x in range(1, 1001) if '5' not in str(x))`

Answer (score 2):

Remove i+=1 from your code because you are running a for loop here so for loop is responsible to increase the value of i . You don't need to explicitly increase it.

```
sum = 0 
for i in range(0,1001): 
    if '5' not in str(i): 
        sum = sum + i 
    
print(sum)
```

Comment: Yes, but if I type 
`
sum = 0 
for i in range(0,1001): 
    if '5' not in str(i): 
        sum = sum + i 
    print(sum)
print(sum)
`
you can still see the numbers it is adding up and some of them contain the number 5 in it. I want to avoid those numbers completely

Comment: I am not sure how to write code in comments

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of the question , variable name - 'sum' should be avoided as its built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the total sum outside loop. For that, you can put the `print` statement at the same indentation as of the `for`.
So, your code needs to be like this

```
sum = 0 
for i in range(0,1001): 
    if '5' not in str(i): 
        sum = sum + i 
       # i += 1 
print(sum)
```

Edit: @Rus, Since I don't have enough reputations I'm continuing in answer. No, it won't print any number that contains 5. You can add a `print` statement inside the loop to check all the possible integers. Also, please double check  that `for` and `prin(sum)` are in the same block.

Here is the updated code.

```
sum = 0 
for i in range(0,1001): 
    if '5' not in str(i): 
        sum = sum + i 
        print(i)
       # i += 1 
print(sum)
```

Comment: Probably don't need to increment the loop variable: `i += 1` that's getting set by the loop/range.

Comment: I removed it, but it still counts numbers that have the number 5 in it...